# Does Stop-CauRun Stop the Current Server or the Whole CAU action?

Tags: powershell, cluster, windows-server-2012-r2, cluster-aware-updating

When using a `PreUpdateScript` or `PostUpdateScript` with "Windows Cluster Aware Updating" and "Updating Run Profiles" would calling the cmdlet Stop-CauRun do any of the following:

- Would it actually stop the updating process at all?
- Would it stop the updating process on just that node?
- Would it cancel the whole CAU action (meaning no other nodes will update)?

I read over the MS page on this and it wasn't clear on whether the pre/post scripts can help control the CAU process.  For reference:

[Advanced Options and Updating Run Profiles for CAU](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj134224.aspx)